# Custom Bibliography certain fields not showing up

Tags: biblatex

Similar (but not the same) to my previously asked question, i have now encountered that some of my bib item fields are not showing up namely month, city and country

my mew:

```
\documentclass{book}

  \usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear,
  bibstyle=chem-biochem,citetracker=true,
  maxcitenames=2,giveninits=false,
  maxbibnames=99,isbn=false,url=false,
  urldate=comp,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

  \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
     andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
  }

  \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    {\list
 {}
 {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
    {\endlist}
    {\item}

    \addbibresource{LitDaten.bib} 
    \usepackage{filecontents}   

    \begin{filecontents}{LitDaten.bib} 
    @BOOK{Rost2005, 
    AUTHOR = {Rost, Detlef H.}, 
    YEAR = {2005}, 
month = {5},
    TITLE = {Interpretation und Bewertung pädagogisch-Studien -         
    }, 
       EDITION = {2. überarb. u. erw. A.}, 
       ISBN = {978-3-825-28306-3}, 
       PUBLISHER = {Beltz}, 
       city= {kinjuira}, 
country = {tong},
    } 
    \end{filecontents} 

    \begin{filecontents}{Datatop.bib} 
@BOOK{Jeff2021, 
AUTHOR = {Jeff, Jeff H.}, 
YEAR = {1984}, 
month ={2},
TITLE = {something important but unseen        
}, 
   EDITION = {1283}, 
   ISBN = {123-4-567-78999-0}, 
   PUBLISHER = {penugin}, 
   city= {seatle}, 
 country = {italy},
} 
\end{filecontents}

    \begin{document} 

    asdfasdf asd \cite{Rost2005} fasdf asdf \cite{Jeff2021} asdf asdf 

    \printbibliography[title=Bibliography] 

  \end{document}
```

---

Would i have to use

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver
```

to include the missing biblabel fields?

Answer (score 2):

You have two things there. First, `city` and `country` are not fields which biblatex recognizes, and are thus ignored. You have `location` for that. The second is the date format. The style `chem-biochem` sets the option `date = year`, you can revert it to biblatex's default by using `date = comp`. Also, you should prefer biblatex date syntax, in the form `date = {YYYY-MM},`.

In full:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear,
bibstyle=chem-biochem,citetracker=true,
maxcitenames=2,giveninits=false,
maxbibnames=99,isbn=false,url=false,
urldate=comp,natbib=true,date=comp]{biblatex} 
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{LitDaten.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{LitDaten.bib}
@BOOK{Rost2005,
  AUTHOR = {Rost, Detlef H.},
  date = {2005-05},
  TITLE = {Interpretation und Bewertung pädagogisch-Studien},
  EDITION = {2. überarb. u. erw. A.},
  ISBN = {978-3-825-28306-3},
  PUBLISHER = {Beltz},
  location = {Kinjuira, Tong},
}
@BOOK{Jeff2021,
  AUTHOR = {Jeff, Jeff H.},
  date = {1984-02},
  TITLE = {something important but unseen},
  EDITION = {1283},
  ISBN = {123-4-567-78999-0},
  PUBLISHER = {penguin},
  location = {Seatle, Italy},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

asdfasdf asd \cite{Rost2005} fasdf asdf \cite{Jeff2021} asdf asdf 

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and i guess one last thing then ill get off your back, using the misc type to get location to show up, it completely messes up the order of things now, ie. the year the article has been published is now all the way in the back instead of author year title, published, location

Comment: @PeterFesterling That's by-design: the ACS use very different ordering for journal, books and 'other stuff'. As always, the behaviour can be altered if you can point to published _Biochemistry_ articles which do something different in a systematic way.